# ADFS 2016 IE and Edge prompt

Tags: asp.net-mvc, adfs

We have an on site ADFS 2016 server setup to authenticate clients to web applications. This seems to work fine for browsers other than IE or Edge.
When using those browsers the client gets a 401 and gets prompted for their credentials when trying to access the ADFS login page.
This version of ADFS doesn't use IIS so there is nothing to set there.
We made sure the ADFS DNS entry is an A record.
We tried adding the adfs url to the trusted sites in the client browser with no success.
Is there something else that needs to be setup for this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue may relate to your primary authentication setting in ADFS being set to Windows Authentication.  This may be a bit different in Windows 2016, but in 2012 R2, if you open your ADFS console, select **Authentication Policies** in the left-pane and then **Edit Global Primary Authentication** in the right-pane, you can see the primary authentication settings for Extranet and Intranet users.

If you would like Windows Authn to be your primary authentication, you may then need to enable Windows Integrated Authentication in IE / Edge.  There are a couple of steps for this I can provide if this is your case.

**UPDATE**: Appears as though this turned out to be Kerberos and SPN issue.  Your ADFS machine name and ADFS service name should NOT be the same.  The core of the issue I believe is the SPN "HOST/AdfsMachineName" is registered with the AD computer object for the ADFS server and the SPN "HOST/AdfsServiceName" is registered with the ADFS service account.  If **AdfsMachineName** and **AdfsServiceName** are the same, this causes a duplicate SPN scenario.

Comment: I think 2016 is different but in authentication methods, I have: Extranet -
Forms Authentication
Microsoft Passport Authentication


Intranet - 
Forms Authentication
Windows Authentication
Microsoft Passport Authentication

Comment: I added the ADFS url to the trusted sites and set the custom level to use "Automatic logon with current user name and password" like I think you were suggesting and I still get the prompt.

Comment: Are all of those authentication methods selected for your Extranet and Intranet setup in ADFS?  If so, I'm not sure about priority off hand, but I would try only enabling Forms Authentication and see if that allows you to login with forms authn.  If so, but you do in fact want Windows Authn , we can work backwards from here.

Comment: Gilligan, If I disable the WIndows Auth for the intranet then I don't get the prompt in IE. Is this recommended?

Comment: No you shouldn't disable wia. Are you testing on w10 clients only?

Comment: Probably windows 10 and 7 and most likely mobile too. I do want all clients to use the ADFS login page so maybe disabling wia is okay.

Comment: I agree, WIA is desirable for your intranet users.  Though I believe WIA must be enabled, at least for your domain, in IE / Edge at the client.  In IE, go to Internet Options and Advanced tab and in Security section ensure "Enable Integrated Windows Authentication" is selected.  Then, go to Internet Options -> Security tab -> Local intranet -> Sites -> Advanced and add the domain of your site, which can include wildcards such as "*.mydomain.com".

Comment: I already tried that and it didn't work on the domain for IE edge. I always got the prompt. Disabling wia fixed all that.

Comment: Puzzling.  Out of curiosity, are you able to enter your domain credentials when prompted and allowed to proceed to the site?

Comment: No that still results in the 401 unauthorized.

Comment: Here's some info on 401's in ADFS, but it's for ADFS 2 and a descent bit of IIS config, but you may check your spn setting.  When you say it works in other browser, does it work for windows authn or just forms authn? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3044976/adfs-2.0-error-401-the-requested-resource-requires-user-authentication

Comment: In other browsers I get the ADFS login page and since those other browsers don't use WIA I assume it is using forms auth. In the link you sent I checked the SPNs for duplicates, set the SPN for the service account but when I try to add the SPN for the Federation Service Name it aborts because it says it was trying to add a duplicate. With WIA disabled, all tested browsers work fine so I'm tempted to leave it alone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141591/discussion-between-gilligan-and-forwheeler).

Comment: I was able to get this working it seems by renaming the server different from the ADFS service name. Thanks to Gilligan for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the output of the below command.

```
Get-AdfsProperties | Select-Object -ExpandProperty WIASupportedUseragents
```

Should look something like this.

```
PS C:\Users\admin.contoso> Get-AdfsProperties | Select-Object -ExpandProperty WIASupportedUseragents
MSAuthHost/1.0/In-Domain
MSIE 6.0
MSIE 7.0
MSIE 8.0
MSIE 9.0
MSIE 10.0
Trident/7.0
MSIPC
Windows Rights Management Client
MS_WorkFoldersClient
=~Windows\s*NT.*Edge
PS C:\Users\admin.contoso>
```

This controls which user agents, browsers are allowed to do WIA. I suspect this list only contains non IE-Edge user agents.

Comment: I have the same - MSAuthHost/1.0/In-Domain
MSIE 6.0
MSIE 7.0
MSIE 8.0
MSIE 9.0
MSIE 10.0
Trident/7.0
MSIPC
Windows Rights Management Cl
MS_WorkFoldersClient
=~Windows\s*NT.*Edge